# tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable with num_oov_buckets doesn't work in TF Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have created a TF model that uses `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable` for creating a vocab map inside TF Graph. It reads mapping from a text file and assigns `num_oov_buckets=500`. Below is a part of the code -

```py
num_oov_buckets = 500
table_init = tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer('resmap.txt', tf.int64, 0, tf.int64, 1, delimiter=" ")
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(table_init, num_oov_buckets)
```

Using this it runs fine at the time of training and prediction.
I convert this TF model into a Tensorflow serving using below code -

```py
from model import ModelWDN

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f', '', 'kernel')
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('model_version', 1, 'version number of the model.')
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('save_dir', '/home/abhilash', 'Saving directory.')
    FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

    export_path = os.path.join(tf.compat.as_bytes(FLAGS.save_dir), tf.compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.model_version)))
    print('Exporting trained model to', export_path)

    # Creating Model object and initializing all the global variables in TF Graph.
    model = ModelWDN(res_count=21663)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())

    tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, os.path.join('/home/abhilash', 'wdn'))
    print("Model restored.")

    # SavedModel Builder Object
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    # Converting Tensor to TensorInfo Objects so that they can be used in SignatureDefs
    tensor_info_click_hist_str = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.click_hist_str)
    tensor_info_res_to_predict_str = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.res_to_predict_str)
    tensor_info_prob = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.logits_all)

    # SignatureDef
    prediction_signature = (
          tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
              inputs={'click_hist_str':tensor_info_click_hist_str,
                      'res_to_predict_str':tensor_info_res_to_predict_str},
              outputs={'probs': tensor_info_prob},
              method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                sess=sess,
                tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                signature_def_map={'predict_ad_view_prob': prediction_signature},
                main_op=tf.tables_initializer(), 
                strip_default_attrs=False,
                )

    # Export the model
    builder.save()
    print('Done exporting TF Model to SavedModel format!')
```

It is converted without any error and gives correct prediction when I provide any value that exists in the `resmap.txt` which I gave while defining `tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer`. Any value which doesn't exist in this map gives an error in serving when doing curl request but doesn't give any error otherwise (i.e when predicting from TF model inside session). 
Curl request -

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/1:predict -d '{"signature_name": "predict_ad_view_prob", "inputs":{"res_to_predict_str": ["9 18788418 19039855 18771619"], "click_hist_str": ["18198449 18656271 18198449"]}}'
```

Here `9` is the id that is not present in the `resmap.txt`

Below is the error I get when doing a curl request -

```
{ "error": "indices[0] = 21748 is not in [0, 21663)\n\t [[{{node GatherV2_5}}]]" }
```

`resmap.txt` has 21663 key-values and `num_oov_buckets` is set to be 500.

Same input while predicting inside TF session gives correct result -

```
[[0.10621755 0.50749264 0.08582641 0.00173556]]
```

So clearly there is some problem with `num_oov_buckets` & graph having this are not correctly implemented in serving or if I am missing something/incorrectly building `TF SavedModel` then let me know.

**UPDATE - Adding saved_model_cli show and run commands**

```
saved_model_cli show --dir 1 --all
```

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['predict_ad_view_prob']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['click_hist_str'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_3:0
    inputs['res_to_predict_str'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder_5:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['probs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_DOUBLE
        shape: (-1, -1)
        name: Sigmoid:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

```
saved_model_cli run --dir 1 --tag_set serve --signature_def predict_ad_view_prob --input_exprs 'click_hist_str=["50 50"];res_to_predict_str=["50 303960 1 2"]'
```

```
2019-07-18 10:18:54.805220: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-07-18 10:18:54.810121: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.811041: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.811492: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.813643: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.815415: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.815914: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.818528: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.820856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.826085: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-07-18 10:18:54.826234: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.827152: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.827807: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.828138: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-07-18 10:18:54.856561: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2300065000 Hz
2019-07-18 10:18:54.857004: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5635e1749450 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-07-18 10:18:54.857037: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-07-18 10:18:54.984822: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.985784: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5635e36188b0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-07-18 10:18:54.985823: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2019-07-18 10:18:54.986072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987021: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987099: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987152: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987202: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987250: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987362: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-07-18 10:18:54.987554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.988526: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.989347: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.989418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-07-18 10:18:54.995160: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-07-18 10:18:54.995475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-07-18 10:18:54.995629: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2019-07-18 10:18:54.995938: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.996963: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-07-18 10:18:54.997884: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8895 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0718 10:18:54.999173 140274532570944 deprecation.py:323] From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py:339: load (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This function will only be available through the v1 compatibility library as tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load or tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load. There will be a new function for importing SavedModels in Tensorflow 2.0.
W0718 10:18:55.271977 140274532570944 deprecation.py:323] From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1276: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
2019-07-18 10:18:56.953677: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
2019-07-18 10:18:56.979903: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
Result for output key probs:
[[0.14920072 0.07349582 0.12342736 0.12342736]]
```

Comment: 1. Can you share your model so that we can reproduce it at our end.                                   2. Can you try performing inference using "saved_model_cli run" command and confirm if the issue still persist. Refer the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#run_command, for more info.                     3. If "saved_model_cli run" is working fine for you, please share the "saved_model_cli run" and "saved_model_cli show" commands you are using, along with the respective results. Thanks.

Comment: When I do `saved_model_cli run` it is working fine. So `SavedModel` is correctly created but it doesn't work correctly with TF Serving. Anyways where should I share the model ?

Comment: For now, can you share the  "saved_model_cli run" and "saved_model_cli show" commands you are using, along with the respective results.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Updated question with `saved_model_cli show` and `run` commands.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are saving the Model in the path, `/home/abhilash/1`. So, name of the Model in the `curl` command should be `abhilash`, instead of `1` because we should not include version numbers.

The syntax of `Curl` command you are using is not correct, at least, as per the documentation shown in this link, https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker.

It should be something like shown below:

```
curl -d '{"signature_name": "predict_ad_view_prob", "inputs":{"res_to_predict_str": ["9 18788418 19039855 18771619"], "click_hist_str": ["18198449 18656271 18198449"]}}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/abhilash:predict
```

If that doesn't work, can you please share the 
`saved_model_cli show`, `docker run` and `saved_model_cli run` commands you are using, along with the respective results so that we can understand where exactly the issue is.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the curl command because even giving above curl command gives me correct results when the number that I am passing lies in `resmap.txt`. When it doesn't lie in `resmap.txt`, that's when error comes in TF Serving but not in `saved_model_cli run` command.